# Shell script to merge lines separated by blank line

Tags: shell, sed, awk

I have a huge text file (500K lines), with some of the lines split into multiple lines. I am trying to get the records with split lines, show up in a single line. When the line gets split, there is a blank line before the beginning of the next line. Right now, I am looping through each line, testing for string at start (`AAAA|`) to identify if it is a new line or not and then concatenate with next. But this seems to take lot of time and want to know if there is any better way to do this. Also, some of the lines are split into multiple lines and each new record begins with "AAAA|".

Input file:

```
AAAA|XXXX|YYYY|ZZZZ|532920-1*TYCO ELECTRONICS AMP#HDR4-2B-320-PSH2-A*CECO COMPONENT EQUIPMENT CO INC#
AAAA|XXXX|2342342|ADFADFS|A80386DX-33*INTEL CORP#
AAAA|SDFASF|234232322|saddfwq|ER412D-5A*TELEDYNE COMPONENTS#M39016/15-088L*QPL-39016#JMACD-5XL*HI-G INC#914S72101-10L*DRI RELAYS INC#M39016/15-082L*QPL-39016#3SBS1412A2*TYCO ELECTRONICS
CORP#

AAAA|XXXXXXX|5675423|XVASD|N74F132D-T*NXP SEMICONDUCTORS#74F132SC*FAIRCHILD SEMICONDUCTOR CORP#N74F132D*NXP SEMICONDUCTORS#MC74F132D*FREESCALE SEMICONDUCTOR INC#N74F132D,602*NXP SEMICONDU
CTORS#

AAAA|SDFASFSAS|23422|DFGAQWEWE|3SBS1411A2*TYCO ELECTRONICS CORP#914S70301-10L*DRI RELAYS INC#M39016/15-081L*QPL-39016#ER412D-26A*TELEDYNE COMPONENTS#JMACD-26XL*HI-G INC#M39016/15-087L*QPL
-39016#

AAAA|SFRQ3|34543534|NSGBSSDF|3SBS1223A2*TYCO ELECTRONICS CORP#914S60301-10L*DRI RELAYS INC#M39016/15-039L*QPL-39016#914S60301-09L*DRI RELAYS INC#M39016/15-051L*QPL-39016#ER412D-18A/S*TE
LEDYNE COMPONENTS#JMAPD-18XL*HI-G INC#

AAAA|ALSKFJ|1SFAE|ASLKFJSLKSAD|11163-164J*PHILIPS COMPONENTS#SEE_DRAWING_11163-164J*ROHM CO LTD#CF1/4L_164J*KOA SPEER ELECTRONICS INC#SEE_DRAWING_11163-164J*PHILIPS COMPONENTS#CF1/4L
U164J*KOA SPEER ELECTRONICS INC#CF1/4-160K-5%*KOA SPEER ELECTRONICS INC#11163-164J*ROHM CO LTD#131-00164-0053*HONEYWELL CROSS REFERENCE#CF1/4CT52A164J*KOA SPEER ELECTRONICS INC#CF1/4CT52R164J*KOA SPEE
R ELECTRONICS INC#||

AAAA|ASDFAA|1ASFSDAS|ASDFSA|MF 55 D 4323 F*KOA SPEER ELECTRONICS INC#2322156X4324*BC COMPONENTS INC#MF1/4DLT52R4323F*KOA SPEER ELECTRONICS INC#2322 156 X 4324*BC COMPONENTS INC#SFR55432K0
1%*BC COMPONENTS INC#CCF-55 4323 F*VISHAY DALE#CCF-554323F*VISHAY DALE#MF1/4DL_4323F*KOA SPEER ELECTRONICS INC#RN55D4323F*MILITARY SPECIFICATIONS#SFR55 432K0 1%*BC COMPONENTS INC#MF55D4323F*KOA SPEER
ELECTRONICS INC#||
```

Answer (score 4):

With Perl preserving blank lines:

```
perl -ne 'if (!/^$/) { chomp } else { print "\n" } print' input
```

With Perl removing black lines after join:

```
perl -ne 'if (!/^$/) { chomp } print' input
```

Using GNU Sed (does not process the last line in posix mode):

```
sed '/^AAAA/{:l N;/\n./{s/\n//;bl}}' input
```

Comment: Thanks perreal. It is working fine except for one condition which I did not mention clearly in my question. Some of the lines in my datafile are split into multiple lines and in that case this solution is not working. I will update my question to include that.

Comment: One other thing I noticed, when I do: grep "AAAA" oldfile|wc -l  and then same on the newfile, the count I get are different. So that would mean I am loosing out some data?

Comment: It is still not working for the multiple split lines.. example 7th record in my post above.

Comment: @Amogh, added some more stuff, the old sed only works with GNU sed

Answer (score 2):

Assuming only the last column is split into multiple lines:

```
awk -F"|" 'NF>1{if(x)print x;x=""}{x=x $0;}END{print x}' file
```

Comment: This should perform better than my solution, @Guru, I bet you are from unix.com

Comment: @neevek : you won the bet :)

Comment: -1 This will not work if a line is split on a `#`. For example: AAAA|SDFASF|234232322|saddfwq|ER412D-5A*TELEDYNE COMPONENTS#M39016/15-088L*QPL-39016#JMACD-5XL*HI-G INC#914S72101-10L*DRI RELAYS INC#M39016/15-082L*QPL-39016#\n
3SBS1412A2*TYCO ELECTRONICS\nCORP#

Comment: Thanks, can you suggest changes needed for this if the line is split into multiple lines as in my updated post above?

Answer (score 1):

A `sed` version of the algorithm "If a line does not start with `AAAA|` simply concatenate with the previous line:":

```
sed -n '1x;2,${/^AAAA|/{x;s/\n//g;p};/^AAAA|/!H};${x;s/\n//g;p}' your_file.txt
```

As all `sed` script, some explanations are needed:

- `-n` : do not print the pattern space at the end of the script.
- `1x` : remember the 1st line in the hold space (exchange hold and pattern space).
- `2,${...} : for the 2nd to last line.
- `/^AAAA|/{x;s/\n//g;p}`: if the line begins with the new record pattern, save new line in the hold space and get back the previous line for the hold space (exchange hold and pattern space), remove the newlines from the previous record and print it.
- `/^AAAA|/!H` : if the line does not begin with the new record pattern, append it to the previous line in the hold space.
- `${x;s/\n//g;p}` : for the last line, get back the data from the hold space, remove newlines and print.

Answer (score 0):

Is the following command slow?

```
awk '!NF{print line; line=""}{line=line$0}' infile
```

Comment: -1 does not work. Incorrectly combines the first three lines, in the example, into one. All lines must begin with `AAAA|`.

Comment: @dogbane, please revoke that -1, I offer solution based on the OP's description: *When the line gets split, there is a blank line before the beginning of the next line*. the first 4 lines are expected to be concatenated.

Comment: No, the OP clearly says `Right now, I am looping through each line, testing for string at start (AAAA|) to identify if it is a new line or not`.

Comment: Then I must give a -1 to the OP, he confuses me and make me lose 2 points.

Comment: You need to use some common sense as well. This is clearly a pipe-delimited data file. By combining the first three records, you have changed the number of columns in the file. The last column is supposed to be the name of a corporation.

Comment: This will not output the last record.  You need to add `END{print line}`  But in all other aspects, it is correct, as the OP's requirements absolutely do *not* specify the leading `AAAA`, and it is a bad idea to read into poorly specified requirements from a sample solution.  So +1.

Comment: "When the line gets split, there is a blank line before the beginning of the next line". There's no blank line before line 3, that means that lines 1-2 are not the result of splitting, so they do not need to be joined. IOW, you should join the two lines preceding a blank, not all the lines between blanks.

Comment: But I agree that it was confusing.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;$!N;/\nAAAA/{P;D};s/\n//;ta' file
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that every record *should* end in a hash sign. If that's true, then:

```
awk '{printf("%s", $0)} /#$/ {print ""}' filename
```

Comment: Thanks glenn, but all records are not ending with # in my data file.

Answer (score 0):

If a line does not start with `AAAA|` simply concatenate with the previous line:

```
awk 'NR == 1 { previous = $0 }
     NR > 1 && $0 ~  "^AAAA[|]" { print previous; previous = $0 }
     NR > 1 && $0 !~ "^AAAA[|]" { previous = previous $0 }
     END { print previous }' your_file.txt
```

We need to put the `|` between `[]` as it is a special character for extended regular expressions.